# Blender Render stucks every ninth frame

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

i have a scene where the problem is that Blender stucks every ninth frame in the first sample regardless where i start. So for example if i start to render with the first frame till frame 120, it stucks at frame 9. But If start to render with frame 9 to 120 it stucks at eightteen. Anyone who had similar problems before? Really strange.

Comment: in the Output panel > Frame Range > Step, is it another value than 1? Even though it doesn't sound like it's the problem...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But the step is set to 1 :/